# rsync skip subdirectory path but not contents

Tags: rsync

I want to use rsync to copy some files from a folder structure and in the new location have the structure modified slightly. Below is what I currently have and what I'm trying to achive

**Folders:**

Parent/A/1/a,b,c

Parent/A/2/j,k,l

Parent/A/3/x,y,z

Parent/B/1/a1,b1,c1

Parent/B/2/j1,k1,l1

Parent/B/3/x1,y1,z1

**In the new location what I want is**

Parent/A/x,y,z

Parent/B/x1,y1,z1

**what I have is**

PathToParent/A/3/x,y,z

PathToParent/B/3/x1,y1,z1

after using the following command sequence

```
rsync -avzP --exclude=*/1 --exclude=*/2 ../Parent/ remote:../ParentPath/
```

I can easily work around this issue but I was hoping that rsync had an option to allow me to run this is as a single command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't do that transformation.

You can put multiple rsync invocations in a script, however ...

```
rsync -a Parent/A/3/ remote:../ParentPath/A/
rsync -a Parent/B/3/ remote:../ParentPath/B/
```